# Issues with view preview

Tags: views, 8

I'm having an issue when creating a new view. The preview pane, upon refreshing/updating" will, instead of updating in the preview section, force the window to navigate to "admin/structure/views/view/MyView/preview/default/" . It doesn't matter is "auto preview" is checked or if I manually press the "update preview" button. I have no idea what i changed recently to start getting this behaviour. My initial thought is that I removed an important js class from a template but I haven't been able to identify which one. I also know it's a theme issue because reverting to any other stable theme fixes the problem!

Is there a better resource for finding what classes are important for core ajax components because I can't find much on the official documentation. Additionally, has any experienced this and know what I might have changed to get this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out my problem and it had to do with classes as I suspected. For whatever reason, a snippet of javascript that was not previously interfering with the preview functionality just recently started breaking the view. I'm still not entirely sure why but I'm guessing I removed the class in another template and so it was never being rendered and now my javascript was overwriting it.